# How to install the ADT from local folder

Tags: android, adt, eclipse-adt

I have downloaded the SDKManager,Which downloaded some version of Android SDK,How do i install into eclipse.Should the ADT always the Zip file?

Below Pic is what i have.

[image]

I have eclipse juno version,to load SDK,and Reinstall the tools,

Is this only option of reinstalling the ADT Tools

AndroidPlugin - https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/

Or it is there as  part of SDK which i have downloaded.

Can anyone help me on this?

Thanks
Rakesh

Comment: Why are you still using Eclipse ADT? and not Android Studio?

Answer (score 0):

Recommend to use [Android Studio](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html) instead of Eclipse with ADT.

If you really need Eclipse, [this article](http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/installing-adt.html) may help you.

ADT is an Eclipse plugin, SDK setting:

[image]

[image]

[image]